# Selenium for Python: How to initiate a file upload after Send_Keys()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

Using Selenium for Python with Firefox, I am trying to upload a file to a hidden file input field.

I seem to be able to make the input field visible via:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right fileInputWrapper ipadUploadButton')[0].style='display:True';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('fileInput hiddenInput')[0].style='opacity:100';")
```

A string on the webpage saying *No File Chosen* appears.

Next, I do the folllowing:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="fileinput"]')
elem.send_keys('/Users/me/2018-01-29 - SR00281.pdf')
```

Inplace of *No File Chosen*, I can now see the file path as a string on the webpage:
 *2018-01-29 - SR00281.pdf*.

However, nothing is uploaded as far as I can tell.

I cannot find a "Submit" button on the page (hidden or visible). There is a "Upload file" `button` that is normally intended for manual upload, but that opens the file selection dialog box on my MacOS.

I also tried sending Return key to the input field, after inputting the path, via `xp_up_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` but then Selenium gave a `FileNotFound` exception, referring to with the unicode code for the Return Key.

FWIW, this is what the page code looks like for the unhidden input field:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right fileInputWrapper ipadUploadButton" data-bind="visible: isMobileDevice(), enable: app.session.isActive()" style="">
    <span data-i18n="UploadFile">Upload file</span>
    <input class="fileInput hiddenInput" id="fileinput" type="file" accept="image/jpeg,application/pdf,image/png,image/tif" style="opacity: 100;">                    
</div>
```

Is there anything that can be done at this point? Is there perhaps some way for JavaScript or anything else to initiate the actual upload of the inputted path?

Comment: What happens when you send keys to input field? Is there any other `type='file'` input fields? If you need to use `JavaScriptExecutor` to upload file then probably you're doing something wrong. Also note that `style.display` property `True` is incorrect value

Comment: when you manually import a file from the 'import' button do you see a submit button or it get automatically uploaded?

Comment: @Andersson When sending keys to the `input` field (the key sent is the absolute path as a string), it starts displaying that string on the webpage. Nothing else happens. When uploading manually via the conventional upload `button` (another element altogether), it opens the MacOS selection dialog box, and once submitting, it shows a little box on the webpage saying "Uploading files...". That doesn't happen when submitting the path string to the `input` field.

Comment: @Infern0 If uploading a file _manually_, that is done via another `button` element: `<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right dropzone-upload-button dz-clickable" id="newButton" tabindex="0" data-i18n="UploadFile" data-bind="visible: !isMobileDevice(), enable: app.session.isActive()" title="Upload file">Upload file</button>`. I don't seem to be able to send a file absolute path as key to it.

Comment: so basically when you click the button for import there is a windows form that selects the file. On file selection, hidden input gets populated with the absolute path of the file and/or uploads it, depends if you have an additional button for finalize of upload. Try send the absolute path to sendKeys() with import os
absolutepath = os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")

Comment: @Winterflags I mean what happens when you're trying to upload file without executing scripts? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @Infern0 I'm using this: `elem.send_keys('/Users/me/2018-01-29 - SR00281.pdf')`. Is that any different from sending the path as `os.path.abspath`?

Comment: @Andersson If I try `elem.send_keys` while it's hidden, I get the exception: `ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input id="fileinput" class="fileInput hiddenInput" type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard`